# Run PAM script only when logging in using su

Tags: linux, pam

I have a script in `/usr/local/bin` that I reference in `/etc/pam.d/su` using:

```
session  optional  pam_exec.so  stdout  /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

It runs as expected when I login to `user` from `root` using `su - user`, but it also executes when I `exit` or `logout` from `user`. How do I stop it from running when logging out?